# When is a type compatible with another?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

When is a type compatible with another type in C++? I have looked in the standard and cannot find a definition of type compatibility.

Example of usage in the standard (n3690): Section 18.10 runtime support:

> If the parameter parmN is of a reference type, or of a type that is
>   not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for
>   which there is no parameter, the behavior is undefined.

Are types simply "compatible" with each other if they can be implicitly converted to each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible"?

Comment: Compatible in what sense? Without further qualifiers, this doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Compatibility between types? Like the compatibility between derived class and their base classes

Comment: do you mean when can one type be converted to another?

Comment: Let me find an example in the standard...

Comment: What @UKMonkey mentions would be called "convertible" and is clearly defined in the standard.

Comment: N3690 is some intermediate standard draft. It would be more helpful if you quoted something close to an actual standard, like N3337, N4141 or N4659. I, for one, don't have that draft lying around.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have the concept of "compatible type" while C does.

In C, two declarations for the same entity must declare compatible types, while in C++, this constraint is replaced by [[basic.link]/10](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#10):

> After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs are replaced by their definitions), the types specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical, except that declarations for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array bound ([dcl.array]). A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic.

The wording you quoted is a description of `<cstdarg>` header, which comes from corresponding C header. So you can regard "compatible" here as the same concept in C.

Comment: So can two types in C++ be said to be "compatible" if the 4 four points are true?

Comment: @asd Depends on where you want to use the word... For example, in this question you mentioned it without explanation, then people in comments were confused of what you were saying...

Answer (score 0):

When RHS variable can be assigned to LHS variable, then RHS variable's type is comparable for  **type conversation**.
You can read more about type conversation  [here](http://www.edugrabs.com/type-conversion-and-type-casting-in-c/)

Comment: To, whomsoever downvoted, now this answer might seem wrong as question is edited, when I ansered question, it was "When is a type compatible with another type in C++? I have looked in the standard and cannot find a definition of type compatibility.".